# Unclear behavior of "dependsOn"

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, openapi-generator

I am using the [openapi-generator-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-gradle-plugin) to generate classes from an OpenAPI specification. As the rest of my code depends on the generated classes, I want the generation to run before every execution of the build task. According to the documentation one can register this dependency as follows:

```
tasks.compileJava {
    dependsOn("openApiGenerate")
}
```

This also works just fine. However, if I do the same for `build` instead of `compileJava` it fails as the `openAPIGenerate` tasks is registered after `compileJava`.
So there is no real issue to solve here as it works but I would appreciate to understand why it works for `compileJava` but not for `build`. Thanks for the insights already.